# Adding Strings to ArrayList<LinkedList<String>> Java

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist, hashtable

I have a problem with adding String to a ArrayList>. Which is declared

```
ArrayList<LinkedList<String>> table = new ArrayList<>();
```

In the constructor of the class I call ArrayLists ensureCapacity method, which doesn't seem to do what I was expecting. I was thinking it would increase the slots for LinkedList inside it, but it just remains empty.

When I try to call my add method:

```
    public boolean add(String s)
{
    boolean wanted = true;
    if(false)
    {
        wanted = false;
    }
    int index = Math.abs(s.hashCode() % table.size());
    table.ensureCapacity(index);
    table.get(index).addFirst(s);
    return wanted;
}
```

Since the table size doesn't get increased by ensureCapacity, I get java.lang.ArithmeticException: by zero.
How can I work around this?
I pictured this in my head as the ArrayList being the first column in a table, and LinkedLists being the rows. So each slot in the ArrayList references a LinkedList which Strings would be saved in. But since the ArrayList is empty at start and I can't increase with ensureCapacity and using the % operator in the add method it won't increase itself.

Comment: size() returns the number of items in the array list, not the capacity. This will be 0 on the first time, so the MOD (%) operation throws Divide by Zero

Comment: I would assume that `table.size()` is 0 and giving you the  exception your seeing. Maybe put a check that says `if(table.size() == 0) { /*increase table size*/ }`

Comment: Aha! I thought capacity was the same thing as the table size @Bret.

Comment: Yes table.size() is 0, ill try that @ug_ but what will happen if i increase the table size by too little? I want to keep my linkedlists short, is there a way to continously increase the size when lists start getting large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ensureCapacity()` may resize the backing array of the ArrayList, but is doesn't change the number of elements actually stored in the List. Therefore, it doesn't affect the return value of `table.size()`.

`table.get(index)` will return null unless you add at least `index+` elements to your list.

It looks like you are trying to implement something similar to `HashMap` (though `HashMap` uses an array and not an ArrayList).

The only way you can rely of `table.size()` is if you add `n` empty `LinkedList`s to `table`. Then `table.size()` would return `n`, and that would be the size of your table.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm taking a class and to create one was this weeks assignment. After talking to some fellow classmates, they seem to have all set a certain amount of lists in the constructor, I guess I'll try that aswell. Would be cool to make it increase on it's own after a while though.

Answer (score 1):

Just fill the list while it is not big enough with empty `LinkedList`s

```
while (table.size() < EXPECTED_SIZE) {
 table.add(new LinkedList<String>();
}
```